# Capture VS2010/TFS2010 Web Service Traffic in Fiddler

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fiddler

Fiddler is not capturing VS2010/TFS2010 Web Service traffic. How can I make sure this traffic goes through Fiddler's proxy?  It seems to work with VS2008/TFS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft don't want you to access TFS via any other means than the SDK, so they're probably doing something hideous to hide the traffic. You certainly shouldn't use Reflector to disassemble anything you might find in *C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a* even if you were interested in finding out more.